# Best Practice: Temporary Record with has_many association

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I'm looking right now for the best way to solve a current problem: I have two models, **Product** and **Photo**. Photos are associated to a Product through has_many.
When a user creates a new product, she can also add photos using a nested form (carrierwave, jquery), before the actual Product is saved to the database. Since the product doesn't exist yet, I'm looking for the best way to save my photos to the database with the correct association.

A few ways came to my mind:

**1)** I save the Product to the database right away when the user hits "new product", with proper ID and delete it again afterwards if the user hits "cancel". This way I have to mess around a bit with my validations and do some client side validations instead.
Could be a problem if the user closes the browser window duringProduct creation - the product will remain in the database.

**2)** I save it to the database and flag it somehow, with a weird ID or an is_temp field or something like that.. That way I can clean up the database every time the user logs in. "Cance" deletes the thing right away (and all associated photos).

**3)** create a temporary ID in memory and don't save the product yet. I can save the photos though associated to this temp Id and when the user hits finally save, I change the product_id to the new, real Product ID

To me so far, Solution 2 looks like the best and cleanest way to do it, which is kind of similar to Ryan Bates' Guest Record Railscast, but maybe I'm missing something here, and there is a much simpler way.
Any other solutions are highly appreciated.

Thank you so much!

Comment: I usually provide a very simplistic form that only has a few very specific fields. For example, with a product you have an item name and an item number. I'll use a popup (bootstrap or jqueryui dialog) that allows the user to add products to a category without leaving that page by only giving the item number and item name. Then, if they need to add photos, they go into the product edit form where they can do everything else.

Comment: As far as your three solutions, I dislike option 2 because it will leave records in the database that may not be needed until the next time the user logs in (which could be months or even never.) Even if you do it when they log out, What do you consider them loging out? the session timing out? the user clicking "logout"? I would go with either #1 or #3, leaning more toward #1

Comment: Thanks man, I indeed went with #1. I was thinking in terms of #2 deleteing old records with a rake task as a cron, kindof similar to Ryan Bates' Railscast. But now it works great, everybody is happy :-)

thanks again!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use #1 because it's more robust. In particular, it's much more effective for APIs.

This gets you in the habit of building your models so they can be saved and modified in indpendent ways. For example, a user may really want a Product without a Photo.

My real-world app has exactly this setup. When a user tries to create a Product with a Photo that doesn't upload correctly, the Product is still saved correct, validated correctly, etc.

In addition, the app has an API with a call to create a Product, then later another call to add a Photo. It's very useful for the API client to be able to create the Product independently of all the associated photos.

Avoid #2 because it leaves a Product stranded in the database. Worse, that Product has not been validated. This tends to cause problems for other areas of an app, such as reports, unless you force every report query to filter out the stranded records.

Consider #3 only if you want it in a transaction and/or need the fastest speed for this case. Doing it all in memory first does help ensure the transaction has all the pieces it needs, and does save a trip to the database.

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late reply, I got swamped with some other stuff in the meanwhile. 
Thanks so much for your answer, I followed your advice and went this way. I even went a step further and just made them all drafts, so when a user wants to create a product, it gets setup in the database right away, until she explicitly deletes it. I might even add some ajax magic later to save progress while the user is editing. seems pretty bulletproof to me so far, and it works great with my photo uploader. :-)

Thanks again!